# php exec() - max_execution_time and Fatal error

Tags: php, fatal-error

While resizing a bunch of images (about 9000), I use this function:

```
function im_call($_data, &$_im_output, $_debug = IM_DEBUG) {

  ini_set('max_execution_time', '3600');
  exec($_data, $_im_output, $_im_error); // this is line 93
  return $_im_error;

} // end function
```

And after a while (about 30 MINUTES) PHP dies with:

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /some/path/im_lib.php on line 93

(it is the line with exec()... )

How is this possible?

Comment: Do you use windows or linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System calls do not count to the PHP run time and so barely effect `max_execution_time` and `set_time_limit`. If you are calling your script from a webserver, you have to know that the webserver (not PHP) may drop the HTTP connection.

For example:

Apache default configuration:

```
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 180

# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 15
```

Every 15 seconds, send a keep alive, repeat 100 times = 1515 seconds between HTTP Request start and closing of the connection. This is about 25 Minutes, almost half an hour.
Even if this is about Webserver <> Client negotiation and not Webserver <> PHP, the webserver (and client!) still may simply drop the connections after a while.

Scripts taking longer than a few minutes should always run from console. HTTP Servers are not ment to keep a single request alive for hours.

Use PHP scripts from console (linux):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
/* code */
```

In combination with `set_time_limit`, the PHP garbage collector and the settings for more memory, those scripts can run for ages.

Appendix:

> The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive
>   max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script
>   itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution
>   of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations,
>   database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum
>   time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows
>   where the measured time is real.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. Temporary increasing the config values helped.

Answer (score 1):

Use [set time limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Guys... it runs half an hour and after that it dies with 30sec fatal error.

Comment: then try this I proposed, and come back in 30 minutes.

Comment: `set_time_limit()` does not affect HTTP connection and does not affect system calls (`shell_exec`, `exec`, ...)