# PHP Read many files inside a directory

Tags: php

I have seen that this question already exist inside stackoverflow but there isn't an answer for my problem.

I have directory with many files downloaded from another server, I don't know how much files and how much is the dimension can be 1GB I think or 100Mb depends of the external server.

Now I have done in this way:

```
    ini_set("memory_limit","10000M");
    $directory = "xml_uploads/hotel/";
    $xml_files = glob($directory . "*.xml");       
    foreach($xml_files as $file)
    {
        $content = file_get_contents($file, true);
        $xml = new DOMDocument();
        $xml->loadXML($content);
        if($xml){
           //parse xml and save inside database
        } 
     }
```

I don't know if is the better way to insert inside memory_limit a large number like that because I don't know the rela size adn if is too bigger I don't want to stop my server.
Exist another way to parse all the xml files inside a directory?

Thanks

Comment: PHP is not the best solution to integrate data from XML to a database. I may be very slow compared to solutions like Talend http://www.talend.com/products/data-integration

Comment: Well, you're re-assigning `$xml` every iteration so your memory consumption will only be as high as your largest file, although if you've got a 1GB XML file something is wrong somewhere else

Comment: I updated my answer with XML parsing information

Comment: I have many and many xml files some of that large from the server, well how can I handle this? isn't something wrong I have only to parse many and many xml toghether @Bojangles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XML Parsing**

Currently you are using `DOMDocument` combined with `file_get_contents` - that means you have to load your huge XML file to the memory first, and you will always hit a limit whenever a file is bigger than available memory - with the solution below, this is not an issue.

If you are concerned with memory usage of the XML parsing code, you should use a `pull` parser - it is a type of XML parser that doesn't load everything into memory, but allows you to operate only on one entity at a time - this way the memory usage is minimal. In PHP, you may use [XML Reader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php):

```
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open("config.xml");

while ($xml->read()) {
    switch ($xml->name) {
        case "myelem":
             ...
    }
}
```

**Huge directory tree traversal**

Sure! There is a [DirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/DirectoryIterator) and [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator)

Usage is very similar:

```
foreach(new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $fileInfo)
{
    if($fileInfo->getExtension() !== 'xml') continue;
    $content = file_get_contents($fileInfo->getPathname(), true);
    ...
}
```

Also, if you have a nested directory structure, you may use the other one:

```
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory)) as $fileInfo)
{
    if($fileInfo->getExtension() !== 'xml') continue;
    $content = file_get_contents($fileInfo->getPathname(), true);
    ...
}
```

note that since this iterator is recursive, we have to wrap it with `RecursiveIteratorIterator`;

both of these are available since PHP 5 (and you really should not use anything below that)

Comment: I think OP's question is mostly about memory management and handling huge xml files.

Comment: I don't need the part of parser because that already works fine

Comment: So what do you need exactly then? Please be more specific - I thought you were concerned with memory consumption, so I pointed out a better solution

Comment: @WebDesigner I added another update  to clarify how that is different from your `DomDocument` code; if that is still not what you were asking about, then clarify your question

Comment: The problem is only the usage of memory because I open and parse many and many file with more lines

Comment: @WebDesigner Then you should not load them into memory with `file_get_contents()`; rather than that, you should use a different parser that will operate on a stream (`XMLReader` I referred to)

Answer (score 0):

Using below code you can get the size of file gonna be upload (before uploading you will get a size of file using js) then you can use ajax to upload a file and adjust memory size accordingly.

***Please remove unwanted code, if not needed***

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Show File Data</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function showFileSize() {
var input, file;

// (Can't use `typeof FileReader === "function"` because apparently
// it comes back as "object" on some browsers. So just see if it's there
// at all.)
if (!window.FileReader) {
bodyAppend("p", "The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
return;
}

input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
if (!input) {
bodyAppend("p", "Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
}
else if (!input.files) {
bodyAppend("p", "This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
}
else if (!input.files[0]) {
bodyAppend("p", "Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
}
else {
file = input.files[0];
alert("File " + file.name + " is " + file.size + " bytes in size");

//bodyAppend("p", "File " + file.name + " is " + file.size + " bytes in size");
}
}

function bodyAppend(tagName, innerHTML) {
var elm;

elm = document.createElement(tagName);
elm.innerHTML = innerHTML;
document.body.appendChild(elm);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action='#' onSubmit="return false;">
<input type='file' id='fileinput'>
<input type='button' id='btnLoad' value='Load' onclick='showFileSize();'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No I need a script without using button, is a cronjob file..and this script I think that doesn't resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Adam's answer is already pointing out good classes, I have a few more hints for you:

When you do huge file things and time/memory consuming things, you can't hit that script from your browser. The server mostly has limited KeepAlive and Timeout, which will kill your script even with 1 TB memory.

Give your script a shebang, make it executable (chmod +x or chmod 700) and hit it from console (http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php).

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// set memory limit here..
// set time limit:
set_time_limit(0)

// maybe enable garbage collector here
// http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php
```

See also this answer someone having similiar problem:

[php exec() - max_execution_time and Fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766989/php-exec-max-execution-time-and-fatal-error/18767371#18767371)